# How to get object from database in Fixtures Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create fake posts with PostFixtures class . I use fake data with "title, slug, content, pushlish_at". But with "author" , i want use data from database (user table). I don't know how to get it. Please help me!

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Faker\Factory;
use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;


class PostFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i< 10; $i++) {
            $post = new Post();

            $post->setTitle($faker->title());
            $post->setSlug($faker->slug());
            $post->setContent($faker->paragraph());
            $post->setPublishAt($faker->dateTimeBetween('-100 days', '-1 days'));

            $userRepository = $manager->getRepository(User::class);
            $user = $userRepository->find(rand(1, 3));
            $post->setAuthor($user);

            $manager->persist($post);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

}
```

In database, I just have three users (id from 1 to 3). And I created ManyToOne relation between Post and User class. But I don't know why $user is null.

**UPDATE**

`UserFixtures` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public const USER_REFERENCE = 'users';
    private $passwordEncoder;

    /**
     * UserFixtures constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }


    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user1 = new User();
        $user1->setEmail('tien@gmail.com');
        $user1->setPassword(
            $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user1,
                '123456'
            )
        );
        $user1->setRoles(['ROLE_ADMIN']);
        $manager->persist($user1);
        $manager->flush();
        dump($user1); // it still has value
        $this->addReference(self::USER_REFERENCE, $user1);
    }
}
```

`PostFixtures` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Faker\Factory;
use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;

class PostFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $faker = Factory::create('en_US');

        $user =  $this->getReference(UserFixtures::USER_REFERENCE);
        dd($user);  // I want to check it: $user still has id . But 
                   // email,role and password are null

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $post = new Post();
            $post->setTitle($faker->title());
            $post->setSlug($faker->slug());
            $post->setContent($faker->paragraph());
            $post->setPublishAt($faker->dateTimeBetween('-100 days', '-1 days'));
            $post->setAuthor($user);
            $manager->persist($post);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            UserFixtures::class,
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked that the user fixtures have actually run before the post fixtures run?  obviously its not getting anything from its query.

Comment: is the User data from fixtures too? or it already in database?

Comment: User data already in database. My first idea is get user which is exist already from database and pass them into `$post->setAuthor(...)` in `PostFixtures` class. But I realized this way seems impossible (or there is another way that I don't know). Then I followed DoctrineFixturesBundle document. But it still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely looking for reference API which is defined under `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture` namespace.

In your `UserFixtures` definition do this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setName(...);

$manager->persist($user);
$this->addReference('user_john', $user);
...
$manager->flush();
```

And then in your `PostFixtures`

```
$post = new Post();
$post->setAuthor($this-getReference('user_john'));
```

and don't forget to add dependencies, so Doctrine will know an exact order (upload users before articles)

```
public function getDependencies()
{
    return [UserFixtures::class];
}
```

This solution implies that you are loading users using fixtures as well, which is a recommended approach.

Comment: I followed you, but in `PostFixtures` class, `$this-getReference('user_john')` is null. I tried using `dump($user)` in `UserFixtures` class and I see it still had value, but when i share to `PostFixtures` class, it's null. I see your way like [https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) , and I see this document just has version 3.0, but my project is version 5.0. Maybe it doesn't apply to Symfony 5 ?

Comment: @NguyenNhutTien so you are saying that when fixtures are done there is no user set to the post? in database?

Comment: OMG, it was my fault. I wanted to use `dd($user)` to check step by step,  I thought when `UserFixtures` was just finished running, $user will be stored in database.    But maybe it's wrong. I removed `dd($user)` and let both `UserFixtures` and `PostFixture` were run. And it worked well. Thank you so much !!